# Text/Design Tab Missing New Android Project on Android Studio IDE

Tags: android, android-studio

How can I enable the text/design Tab on the a src/main/res/layout folder on the activity_main.xml file that was created automatically during create new project? If i do right click and create xml file on the said folder, the design/text tab exist. Any suggestion? Thanks.

No Text/Design Tab on the Bottom Part of the Android Studio 
[image]

Creating a new XML in the Res/Layout Folder, the design/text tab is now present. 
[image]

Any help? this is super weird guys...

Comment: I had this problem from a fresh install and new project created by the wizard. No tabs. Close file, re-open (wasn't in recent files!) from project pane, and now it has Design/Text tabs. Buggier than Eclipse!

Comment: Did you build the project? If not, you need to do this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I had the same problem, restarting the IDE did make that tab appear again.

Comment: It did appear again.. So this is a bug and not a setup problem.

Comment: @The you should consider accepting [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60162354/10147399) answer instead.

Answer (score 88):

In **Android Studio 3.6** use these three buttons (Code | Split | Design), on top right, to switch between views.

[image: Split button at top right]

Comment: Thank you!  Would have been nice if they let you know that after the upgrade.

Comment: This would be the answer most people are looking for now, when they start the program after 3.6

Comment: Wow, not liking the new design. Agree, a heads up would've been nice.

Comment: I really want to move that icons to previous place

Comment: This fixed my issue as well. Thanks

Answer (score 5):

On Android Studio 3.6.1 
Top Right corner under the main toolbar you have three different icons (Code, Split, Design).

Answer (score 4):

```
View -> Tool windows -> Preview .
```

Output view:

[image]

Answer (score 4):

use the three buttons (Code|Split|Design)on top right hand side to switch between views.

Answer (score 3):

I also had this problem after upgrading to 1.5. None of the above suggestions worked for me. I noticed that the default relative layout xml has changed with a third xmlns line and an app behavior line. I opened an older project and copied the old relative layout header to replace the new. Instantly the preview function was restored.

Comment: I am using the latest version 2.3.3
... but this problem occured.

Answer (score 3):

You can also Move between Design / Text tabs in layout’s view with simple shortcut:
(Mac) : control + shift + ← / →
(Windows / Linux): alt + shift + ← / →

Answer (score 3):

On the top right corner of the activity_main.xml file view, there are 3 icons representing "Code", "Split" and "Design". Click on the leftmost icon of the three ("Code") for the text tab.

Answer (score 2):

In the android Studio window, at the left side there are two options available(**Project and Resource Manager**). Go to resource and there you will see an **ADD Module option**, click on that. After this you will see your text and design option will get enabled, you can go to your work area by **Project Name->app ->src ->main->res ->layout**.

Answer (score 1):

Navigate to **activity_main.xml** tab then Design and Text tab appears.
It doesn't appear in **MainActivity.java** tab.
You do not need to restart IDE.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Even I had the same problem. For the first time... I think It wont show, restarting the IDE did make that tab appear again.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem too, I deleted all the preference files, such as the AndroidStudioPreview folder & com.google.android.studio.plist, then restarted android studio, it worked.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to restart an IDE. All you need is to close an xml file that does not get a tab and reopen it within an editor. It is a little bug.

Answer (score 0):

If text/design tab is missing in new android studio, this can solve by two methods.
You have re-install android studio. And don't forget to delete android studio related all files from temp and local.
Or you can re-install SDK (software development kit) according to your device.

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to try **File->Repair IDE**, it will take you through some steps and one of them must fix this issue.