# I can't find the Design tab in my XML file in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

[image]I imported a project in my android studio and I am trying to edit the positioning of the buttons and some stuff of the GUI but I can't seem to find the design tab in the .xml file. Can someone please help me? Thanks

Comment: you mean Layout Preview?

Comment: @Yurets yep. The phone in which I can drag the objects in.

Comment: here it is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16660039/where-is-android-studio-layout-preview , no wait, that is different, sorry

Comment: @Yurets That's also my problem but I can't see any preview in my window. The Tool Windows inside View doesn't show any "Preview" option

Comment: the answer above has at least 3-5 ways how to open "Preview". Take a look.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Many people suggest to restart `IDE`, but here is simplified way.
You can find the design tab -> View -> Tool Windows -> Design. See screenshot.

[image]

*UPDATE*

Found second way. Do you see the "Text" tab? Right click -> Select next/previous tab in multi-editor file. For me it switch from one tab to another.

[image]

Comment: I am not able to click the Designer option. When I click it, the menu only closes and nothing happens.

Comment: try to restart `IDE`, wish it helps

Comment: updated answer, try that way. if it will not work, could you please take a screenshot while layout is opened?

Comment: Where can I see the text tab sir?

Comment: please take a screenshot while layout is opened, so I'll be able to see what you have there. have you tried to restart? I'll take a screenshot with "Text" tab

Comment: This file is `Manifest`, there is nothing to design, so it is not wondering you don't see it. open please a layout file (where you design screen in folder `res/layout`. If you open it and it will not appear again try to close it. Navigate to this file again -> right click -> Jump to source. By default it must open Designer.

Answer (score 5):

I had this problem when upgrading to `Android Studio 3.6` but learned from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18824306/text-design-tab-missing-new-android-project-on-android-studio-ide) post to use the three buttons in the upper right corner to toggle between views.

[image]