# new version of android studio broken? can't find my layout/design area

Tags: android, android-studio

I am having some trouble finding the `design view` in the latest version of Android Studio. The problem that is reported in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30015208/i-cant-find-the-design-tab-in-my-xml-file-in-android-studio) is the same as mine, but the solution provided there does not work for me.

My problem is that my `designer` option is grayed out, and I do not know how to enable it. This is a [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uiRKA.png) of my work space.

Comment: Which version of AS are you running? What folder contains the XML file you are trying to edit?

Comment: Very bottom left; error loading facets. Details. Open that

Comment: Or the event log that's red in bottom right

Comment: which exactly version is latest for you? from which channel?

Answer (score 1):

This is due to not enabling the `Android Support` plugins, `Enable` it from:

> Settings > plugins > Android Support

[image]

Comment: Yes. I found that somehow the plug ins were removed including the android sdk. After reinstalling these and some and their dependencies I was able to use AS again. Thanks! Love this site!