# Toolbar location in Android Studio

Tags: android-studio

I just started learning Android and below is my Layout page shown in the screenshot.I was looking for the toolbar that I could use to drag drop controls example button or edittext. Can you please suggest me the location of toolbar ?

[image]

Comment: do you mean the design palette? - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18824306/text-design-tab-missing-new-android-project-on-android-studio-ide

Comment: Thank You for the link. In the second image given in question, please check the File explorer and then we have controls under layout, Widgets, Text Fields. I am looking for that window.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose you're talking about the design **Palette**.

Click the **Palette** button:
[image]