# Android studio designer view missing

Tags: java, android, gradle, tabs

I recently downloaded Android studio but when I create a new project the design tab is missing and when I go under window tools the preview tab is missing too. So I can't create anything because the design view is not there. Please help

Comment: They moved into the upper-right corner, and changed into three image buttons, instead of the old Text/Design tabs. Have a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60162354.

Comment: Could you please upload your android studio screenshot?