# Android Studio isn't showing the xml editor

Tags: android-studio, ide, editor

I recently updated to version 3.6.3 of android studio and now whenever I click on an xml file in the project window only the preview with the palette and component tree show up.

Before the update clicking on an xml file would show a xml editor. Now I can't access the xml editor in any project.

I've tried looking through the view menu to see if there was some way to enable the xml editor from there with no luck. Also, I've found that I can still edit java files.

I'm sure it's something really simple that I'm overlooking but I just don't know what. Has anyone run into this problem before, and how did you solve it?

Comment: Have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60162354) on the linked post. Those three buttons are what toggle the text/design views now.

Comment: Thank you guys for the help! I figured it was something simple; it was the three buttons in the upper right that did it.