# Android Xml Code, Split and code window does not Appearing in the Xml file in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

[image]Android Xml  Code, Split and code window does not Appearing in the Xml file in Android Studio. I am not able to see the Design of my Layout.

Comment: click with CTRL key to @layout/content_main

Comment: Please post a screenshot instead of a photo of your screen.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Text/Design Tab Missing New Android Project on Android Studio IDE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18824306/text-design-tab-missing-new-android-project-on-android-studio-ide)